# Custom Django field does not return Enum instances from query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, enums, django-custom-field

I have a simple custom field implemented to utilize Python 3 Enum instances. Assigning enum instances to my model attribute, and saving to the database works correctly. However, fetching model instances using a QuerySet results in the enum attribute being a string, instead of the respective Enum instance.

How do I get the below `EnumField` to return valid `Enum` instances, rather than strings?

fields.py:

```py
from enum import Enum

from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.db import models


class EnumField(models.CharField):
    description = 'Enum with strictly typed choices'

    def __init__(self, enum_class, *args, **kwargs):
        self._enum_class = enum_class
        choices = []
        for enum in self._enum_class:
            title_case = enum.name.replace('_', ' ').title()
            entry = (enum, title_case)
            choices.append(entry)
        kwargs['choices'] = choices
        kwargs['blank'] = False  # blank doesn't make sense for enum's
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def deconstruct(self):
        name, path, args, kwargs = super().deconstruct()
        args.insert(0, self._enum_class)
        del kwargs['choices']
        return name, path, args, kwargs

    def from_db_values(self, value, expression, connection, context):
        return self.to_python(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if value is None or isinstance(value, self._enum_class):
            return value
        else:
            return self._parse_enum(value)

    def _parse_enum(self, value):
        try:
            enum = self._enum_class[value]
        except KeyError:
            raise ValidationError("Invalid type '{}' for {}".format(
                value, self._enum_class))
        else:
            return enum

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        if value is None:
            return None
        elif isinstance(value, Enum):
            return value.name
        else:
            msg = "'{}' must have type {}".format(
                value, self._enum_class.__name__)
            if self.null:
                msg += ', or `None`'
            raise TypeError(msg)

    def get_choices(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs['include_blank'] = False  # Blank is not a valid option
        choices = super().get_choices(**kwargs)
        return choices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of digging, I was able to answer my own question:

`SubfieldBase` has been deprecated, and will be removed in Django 1.10; which is why I left it out of the implementation above. However, it seems that what it does is still important. Adding the following method to replaces the functionality that `SubfieldBase` would have added.

```
def contribute_to_class(self, cls, name, **kwargs):
    super(EnumField, self).contribute_to_class(cls, name, **kwargs)
    setattr(cls, self.name, Creator(self))
```

The `Creator` descriptor is what calls `to_python` on attributes. If this didn't happen, querys on models would result in the `EnumField` fields in the model instances being simply strings, instead of Enum instances like I wanted.